# Algebra Problem - Painting a Car

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes $50$ minutes for $10$ people to paint $1$ car. How many minutes will it take $15$ people to paint the car?

I think I have this, I just wanted to make sure.

I have $50\text{ min}/10\text{ ppl}$ for $1$ car. So I multiply by $10$ to get it for $1$ person $\longrightarrow$ $500\text{ min}/\text{person}$ for $1$ car. Then multiply by $1/15$ to get the number of minutes for $15$ people. The answer was $500/15 \approx 33.3$ minutes.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: That is absolutely correct.

Comment: Still 50 minutes -- more than 10 painters would just get in each other's way.

Comment: Why not invite 1000 people to paint the car and get it over with in half a minute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You are correct.

$50*10=500$minutes. Then, $500/15=33.33...$minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is perfectly correct. Since a different number of people are doing the **same** job, you could just do a *cross-multiplication* like this :

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
&\text{Case 1} &\text{Case 2}\\
\hline
\frac1{\text{Nb. persons}} & \frac1{10} & \frac1{15}\\
\text{Time needed} & 50 & \text{?} \\
\end{array}
$$

Note that when you do this, you should have the second line increasing when the first line does, that's why we couldn't keep $\text{Nb. persons}$ and $\text{Time needed}$ but had to take the inverse of one of them.

The *cross-multiplication* tells you that in an array like this :

$$
\text{bottom-left} \times \text{upper-right} = \text{bottom-right} \times \text{upper-left}
$$

In our problem, that gives :

$$
50 \times \frac1{15} = \text{?} \times \frac1{10}
$$

Hence the number we are looking for is :

$$
\frac{50 \times \frac1{15}}{\frac1{10}} = \frac{50 \times 10}{15} = \frac{10 \times 10}{3} = 33.333...
$$

---

What you need to remember is that for problems like this, you can always do a [*cross-multiplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication), just pay attention to the numbers you put in, there must not be one increasing while the other decreases.

---

Other really important fact, in your particular problem, you need to make sure that the people are doing the **same** job. Otherwise you could fall into a nice well-known trap : *If it takes $1$ day for $8$ hens to lay $8$ eggs, how long does it take for $80$ hens to lay $80$ eggs ?*

Here the jobs (laying eggs) are different since the number of eggs to lay is not the same. Therefore you cannot directly apply the *cross-multiplication*.

---

This will all become very natural with a bit of [practice](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/cross-multiply.html), I guarantee it ;)

Have fun !